# Unable to display captcha while using jsoup to extract a division in android webview

Tags: android, webview, jsoup, captcha, division

I am using the following code to fetch a division of a webpage using htmlunit.

```
String url="url";
String divisonname="dv";
WebView  w=(WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage(url);
HtmlElement imgElement = currentPage.getHtmlElementById(divisionname);
```

Now, i don't know how to load this fetched data into webview.I just know this command `w.loadurl(url);`

Comment: Jsoup cannot execute JavaScript to get the dynamic HTML that is the result of the JavaScript.

Comment: Then how could you tell me any other method that will do the required functionality.

Comment: Well, use some library that can execute JavaScript. Use Google.

Comment: There are a lot of answers about parsing html and executing javascript. Check webdriver (selenium) or HtmlUnit.

Comment: I have looked into a number of pages in google, but they are of no use. They do not describe how to use it in android webview to load a specific division from a url containing dynamic content.

Comment: can anyone post the code to load a specific division from a url containing dynamic content in webview using webdriver (selenium) or HtmlUnit.

Comment: The problem is that you are not showing any of your own effort. You only say what your problem is and assume others will fix it for you. This is a Q&A-site where you have to provide some of your own efforts to resolve a specific problem. What have your tried with HtmlUnit? Really, you can't expect people will just be able to write code that magically works for you?

Comment: @DanielB Now I have updated my code, now if you can assist me further, it will be very helpful.